# Get running VMs on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I have the below code to check daily if all the VMs that are meant to auto-start have started successfully.

```
$Date = (Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm").toString()
$Results = "C:\temp\DailyChecks_$($Date).txt"

$Cred = get-credential -UserName 'AZ-User'

Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'TenantID' -credential $Cred | out-null

$fCount = (Get-AzVM -Status | Where-Object { $_.tags['Managed By'] -like 'Manager' }).count

do {
    $rCount = (Get-AzVM -Status | Where-Object { $_.tags['Managed By'] -like 'Manager' -and $_.PowerState -eq 'VM Running' }).count
    if($rCount -lt $fCount)
    {
        write-host "There are $rCount VMs running, checking again"
    }
    elseif($rCount -eq $fCount){write-host "There are $rCount VMs running, exiting loop"}
}until($fCount -eq $rCount)

Get-AzVM -Status | Where-Object { $_.tags['Managed By'] -like 'Manager' } |
Select-Object Name, PowerState | Format-Table | out-file $Results
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a better way to write this code?
2. How can I check if the code has been running for longer than 30 minutes and yet not all VMs are running?

Comment: Code-wise, improvements I would made is to declare a variable before the loop (eg: `$vms`) and then set the result of `Get-AzVm` , something like `$Vms = (Get-AzVM -Status | Where-Object { $_.tags['Managed By'] -like 'Manager' })` . All that so you don't have to make that last call after the loop to `Get-AzVm` yet another time but just use the last result obtained, which is when all the vms were started. You can still get your `$rcount` through `$rcount = ($vms | Where-Object PowerState -eq 'VM Running').count`

Comment: You could also add a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 60` or whatever value seems reasonable to prevent the api call to be done immediately one after another. Resource-wise, that is never good even if it might not be a problem in that case. More logically, if not all the VMS are started at X point in time, do you really want to poll the server 1 ms after (even though it take time to return) ? ... It is just a matter of pacing the calls out to something that make sense rather than intensively polling the fastest possible. On some API, you would get errors after some time (quotas related)

Comment: @SagePourpre I plan to schedule the script to start 5 minutes before the scheduled VM start time on Azure. At that point, the variable will have 0 machine that are running, which is why I'm calling the `Get-AzVm` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine for how much the time the script is running by using a StopWatch object.

```
$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
$sw.Start()
```

Whenever you want, just check the elapsed time by checking the elapsed property

```
$sw.Elapsed
$sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
Write-Host "Time elapsed: $([Math]::Round($sw.Elapsed.TotalMinutes,0)) min $($sw.Elapsed.Seconds) seconds"
```